# Codility test - find multiples in range

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity

I applied for a job and was asked to do a Codility test. The test was the following:

Return the number of integers within the range [A..B] that are divisible by K.

Args:

- A: is an integer within the range [0..2,000,000,000]
- B: is an integer within the range [0..2,000,000,000] and A <= B
- K: is an integer within the range [1..2,000,000,000]

Time complexity must be O(1).

I know my solution isn't O(1), I couldn't come up with a better solution than this.
Can anyone enlighten me?

BTW, it's in C# so 'int' is large enough to hold 2000000000.

```
public int solution(int A, int B, int K) 
{
    int i=0;

    for(int x=A;x<=B;x++)
    {
        if((x % K) == 0)
            i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is slightly simplified solution that will be incorrect when A = 0 (*Edit*: it looks like this will work even when A = 0, but the second version at the end of the answer is more clear).

First, define a function that returns number of numbers up to N that K divides:

In Python:

```
def result_upto(n, k):
    return n // k
```

Then the answer will be just result_upto(B, k) - result_upto(A - 1, k).

*Edit.* Let's fix it for the case when A = 0.

Zero can be divided by anything, so we have such test cases:

```
// solution(A, B, K)
solution(0, 0, 1) = 1 // 0
solution(0, 1, 1) = 2 // 0, 1
solution(0, 5, 2) = 3 // 0, 2, 4
```

Updated function can be:

```
def result_upto(n, k):
    if n >= 0:
        return n // k + 1 % account for zero
    else:
        return 0
```

Then the answer is still just result_upto(B, k) - result_upto(A - 1, k).

Comment: This worked! I just did (B/K)-((A-1)/K) - multiples of K in whole range minus multiples in lower range.  Thanks.

Comment: Should mention it's a combination of @herohuyongtao/@Sergeys answers. Thanks to both of you for your help.

Answer (score 18):

Here's my solution in Java, score 100%

```
public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {

    int count = (B/K - A/K) + (A%K == 0 ? 1 : 0);

    return count;
}
```

Comment: The perfect answer. The same code works also for C#!

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `(B-A) / K` plus boundary checking is ok enough.

---

**Edit**:

1. Don't just copy `(B-A) / K` to use, though this will be the bone-structure code, you need to add correct boundary checking. Regard this as a way of thinking.
2. For those who think `O(n)` is needed for boundary checking, you are wrong. **O(1)** is enough for boundary checking. You only need to check the relationship of A/B vs. K.

Comment: Thanks, calling solution(6,10,2) with this logic returns 2, which is wrong. Should be 3.

Comment: I don't see this approach working. For example, imagine some large K and some A and B, so B-A is large, but still B-A < K. So (B-A) / K = 0. But inside [A; B] can be a number that is divisible by K. To find if there is such a number we'll have to check O(B-A) numbers, so "boundary checking" is really O(n).

Comment: @user2669338 Of course, you cannot just simple use `(B-A) / K`. Like I said, you need to figure out correct boundary checking. Regard this as a way of thinking.

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko No, `O(1)` is enough for boundary checking. You only need to check the relationship of `A`/ `B` vs. `K`.

Comment: This logic is correct, however the formula should be (B - (A - 1))/K as A and B is inclusive

Comment: @PhamTrung Yeah, it does. Just want to show the logic here. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Since, we are not required to know what are those numbers we can simply find the count by following way:

```
  public long solution(long low, long high, long K)
  {
     return (((high - low)/K) + 1);
  }
```

For Example:
0..100 by 5 = 21

Complexity: O(1)

Answer (score 0):

Solution that can be one liner for O(1) is:

```
int boundaryCheck = (1 - (int)Math.signum(A % K)) + (1 - (int)Math.signum(B % K));
if( K < A) {
    return(((B- A - 2) / K) + boundaryCheck);
}else if (K < B){
    return(((B - A - 1) / K) + boundaryCheck + (1 - Math.signum((B - A)/ K)));
} else {
    return(boundaryCheck);
}
```

We should consider 3 cases, K

1. If A is not dividable by K, , then the sign is 1 which means that we should not increase number by one (so we calculate it by 1-1)

Comment: Consider A = 1, B = 2, K = 2.

Your solution: ((B-A) / K) + (1 - Math.Sign(A % K)) = ((2-1) / 2) + (1 - Math.Sign(1 % 2)) = 0 + (1 - 1) = 0.

Correct solution is of course 1.

Comment: This worked with most cases, but when called with solution(1,3,3) it returned 0, the answer should've been 1.

Answer (score 0):

find `m1=A%K` and `m2=B%K` and use arithmetic progression to find the total nos in the range by using following formula.

```
m1 = A%K;
m2 = B%K;

if(m1>0)
a = A + K - m1;

b = B - m2;

if(b>=a) {

 total = (b-a)/K + 1;
}

else total = 0;
```

The above is `O(1)` solution

Answer (score 0):

```
public static  int solution2(int A, int B, int K)
        {
            return (int)Math.Floor(((B - A) % (double)K));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void CheckDivisibility(int A,int B, int k)
        {
            int firstdivisorpos = A + (k- (A%k));
            int lastdivisorpos = B-B%k;
            int totalnosdivisble = (lastdivisorpos - firstdivisorpos)/k;
            Console.WriteLine(totalnosdivisble+1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A much more efficient way is to simple produce multiples of C from A to B so you do not need to check each value necessarily. The large the C the more efficient it will be.

```
do 
{
    int a = start + (C * i++);
    if (a >= A && a <= B)
    {
        //display a;
    }
    if (a > B)
        break;
}while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java11 stream API to solve this.

```
public long solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    return IntStream.iterate(A, n -> n <= B, n -> n+1)
                    .filter(n -> n%k==0)
                    .count();
}
```

The benefit of using Java Stream API is that we can make the stream parallel for better performance if we have a large dataset.